# Is there any open source outliers miner for databases

Tags: data-mining, business-intelligence, outliers

I am looking for an open source outliers detector. I know that it is possible to realize such detector using rapidminer/knime/wekka but I wonder if there is already such a tool.

Comment: A related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026067/outlier-detection-in-data-mining

Answer (score 2):

The database group at the University of Munich publishes a piece of open source software that includes various outlier detection algorithms, including the local outlier factor. The package also includes tools for visualization of results.

The toolkit is called [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) and available as open source software.